# Laravel 4 Controllers, handling default route?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Let's say I have a `UsersController`.  In that controller there is a handler for `website.com/users/login` and `website.com/users/register`

How would I handle a route of `website.com/users` within the controller similarly how I would with the other handlers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In routes.php:

```
Route::controller('users', 'UserController');
```

In UserController.php:

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex()
    {
        # GET website.com/users 
    }

    public function getLogin()
    {
        # GET website.com/users/login   
    }

    public function getRegister()
    {
        # GET website.com/users/register    
    }

}
```

The Laravel docs have more examples: http://four.laravel.com/docs/routing